# Images are not displayed in android list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, mobile-application

I'm making a todo app and when an item is marked as finished an image should be displayed in front of the list item. But images are not visible in the list view even if the item status in the database is changed as finished.

**This is my adapter class.**

public class ToDoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private int resource;
List<ToDoModel> todos;

public ToDoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<ToDoModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.todos = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //Inflate card view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

    TextView title = row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img_done);
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Set data in card view
    ToDoModel todo = todos.get(position);
    title.setText(todo.getTitle());
    description.setText(todo.getDescription());

    //Show done image
    if(todo.getFinished() > 0){
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return row;
}
```

}

**This is MainActivity.**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView todoList;
private TextView countTxt;
private Button addTodo;
private List<ToDoModel> toDos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    todoList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
    countTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
    addTodo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    toDos = new ArrayList<>();

    addTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Go to next activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddToDO.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DBHandler dbh = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());

    //Set count
    int count = dbh.getCountTODO();
    countTxt.setText("You have " + count + " TODOs");

    //Save list
    toDos = dbh.getAllToDos();

    //Set adapter to list
    ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.todo_cardview, toDos);
    todoList.setAdapter(toDoAdapter);

    //Add click listener to list element
    todoList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Get clicked item
            ToDoModel todo = toDos.get(position);

            //Dialog box
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(todo.getTitle());
            builder.setMessage(todo.getDescription());

            //Buttons
            builder.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dbh.deleteItem(todo.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ToDo Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Finished", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //Update status
                    dbh.updateFinished(todo.getId(), time);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            });


            builder.setNeutralButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddToDO.class);
                  intent.putExtra("id", todo.getId());
                  intent.putExtra("title", todo.getTitle());
                  intent.putExtra("description", todo.getDescription());
                  intent.putExtra("finished", todo.getFinished());
                  startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Try moving everything in `onResume()` to `onCreate()`.

Comment: why open activity again? you should update your list view. change data of adapter and call notify.

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide or Picasso Library to Displaying Image with any other Shape.

Glide Example:

Glide.with(mContext).load(responseList.getLogoUrl()).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(holder.imageName);

Picasso Example:

Picasso.get().load(clsobjname.getLogoUrl())
.into(viewHolder.imagename);